# Are there any e-commerce taxation rules in India?

Tags: taxes, india

I am planning to sell my software online, by recieving payments through Debit,credit cards and netbanking. Are there any e-commerce taxation rules like in the European Union..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no clear guidelines. If you are selling as individual, then what ever profit you make gets added to your overall income as you pay tax accordingly. This is true for sole proprietor or partnership kind of firms.

If you are registered as a Company, the profits are taxed as business income. There may be VAT and other taxes.

Please consult a CA who can guide you in specifics as for eCommerce, there is no defined law and one has to interpret various other tax laws.